# Unknown account error when running smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum

I get the unknown account error when executing smart contract on the main network.
it works well on the local network. On the main network on the other hand when i send funds to the smart contract it goes well but when i call the smart contract i get the "unknown account" error.
Anyone have any ideas why i get that? Thank you

Comment: How are you calling the contract, can you show your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown account error- smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51479/unknown-account-error-smart-contract)

Comment: function confirm_transaction (address buyer, string trxId) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {

     if(trx_status[buyer][trxId] == false) {
      seller_address = trx_seller[buyer][trxId];
   amount_transaction = trx_amount[buyer][trxId];

   seller_address.transfer(amount_transaction);
   trx_status[buyer][trxId] = true;

   emit LogConfirmTransaction(buyer, trxId);
     }